# translating a SQL query into a LINQ to SQL query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How can I write this query using LINQ?

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN [IsForReplication] = 1  THEN 'Yes' 
                   ELSE 'No' END AS NCHAR) as [IsForReplication], * 
FROM [SAN].[dbo].[PolicyInterval]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from pi in context.PolicyInterval
            let IsForReplication = pi.IsForReplication ? "Yes" : "No"
            select new
            {
                IsForReplication,
                PolicyInterval = pi,
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = PolicyInterval.Select(entry => new {IsForReplication = entry.IsForReplication.Equals(1).ToString(), data = entry});
```